# What CN name should I use when I want to setup SSL on port other then default 443?

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, apache-2.4

I have server that runs both my public web server, and local one. Local server is on port 333, and I used invalid certificate for it for a long time, but I want it to be properly configured, so I made my own CA, installed the root authority on my machines so it won't give me "Self-signed" certificate error, created certificate for my server, setup apache2, but now there is a CN error. I tried couple of variants of CN, I tried server.home:333, server.home, and server.home:*, but no luck. Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: There is a lot of detail missing from your post. How did you create the certificate authority? How did you create the certificates? What is the error that you received?

Comment: CN of a certificate and tcp port of the http server have nothing to do with each other. CN should however match the name defined in the ServerName directive of each virtualhost with SSL enabled

Comment: Related question from the Information Security Stack Exchange: [Do SSL / X.509 certs cover all ports for a host?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/62900/13584)

Answer (score 5):

The port the server is running on is not relevant when checking the certificate and should not be included in the certificate. Storing the server name in the CN is obsolete though: Chrome will completely ignore the CN and other clients will ignore CN if names are defined using subject alternative names (SAN). Thus, use SAN to specify the domain name.